# I Want Show Custom Dialog like iphone HUD Progress Bar

Tags: android

I want to show custom dialog like iphone hud progress Bar Style.but,i am no idea for creating custom dialog like hud progress bar like iphone on android.

I want custom dialog like below image:

[image]

Help with me...!

Thanks...!

Comment: First and most thing, **Every platform has their own standards, for UI and programming**.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have created a sample Android application and a ProgressHUD class which you can use for this purpose. You can find it here:
https://github.com/anupamdhanuka/AndroidProgressHUD

Answer (score 1):

Just look at this(my) library. [IOSDialog/Spinner library](https://github.com/Samehadar/IOSDialog)

It is very easy to use and solves your problem. With it, you can easily create and use spinner like in IOS.
The example of code:

```
final IOSDialog dialog1 = new IOSDialog.Builder(IOSDialogActivity.this)
            .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    dialog0.show();
                }
            })
            .setDimAmount(3)
            .setSpinnerColorRes(R.color.colorGreen)
            .setMessageColorRes(R.color.colorAccent)
            .setTitle(R.string.standard_title)
            .setTitleColorRes(R.color.colorPrimary)
            .setMessageContent("My message")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setMessageContentGravity(Gravity.END)
            .build();
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3LVY.gif)

```
 final IOSDialog dialog0 = new IOSDialog.Builder(IOSDialogActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Default IOS bar")
            .setTitleColorRes(R.color.gray)
            .build();
```

Result: standard IOS Dialog

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks for the advice. I indicated that this is my library. And the picture is attached, but due to the fact that I have a small reputation, I can only leave a link to it.

Comment: A link is fine, because the image is big and a little distracting.

Answer (score -1):

```
       private class loadassync extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            classname.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        this.dialog.setMessage("loading.....");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {

        //add the logic while loading
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {

        try {
            //add the logic after loading
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

to execute assynctask

```
     Loadassync mAssyn1 = new LoadAssync();
                mAssyn1.execute();
```