# How can i draw a shape circular but zigzag in android?

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to draw a shape circular but zigzag in android as per attached image

[image: attached image]

trying this type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="@dimen/circleProgressRadius"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="@dimen/circleProgressThickness">

            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/circleProgressIncompleteStartGradient"
                android:endColor="@color/circleProgressIncompleteEndGradient"
                android:type="sweep" />   
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But not getting shape as per attached image How can i do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I Want Show Custom Dialog like iphone HUD Progress Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311521/i-want-show-custom-dialog-like-iphone-hud-progress-bar)

Comment: It is not a progress bar

Comment: I want only shape like this not progress bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw this image we can go like this

circle_progress_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:height="10dp" android:width="10dp" />
    <stroke android:width="7dp"
        android:dashGap="3dp"
        android:dashWidth="0.5dp"
        android:color="#000"/>
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

in main activity

```
android:layout_width="178dp"
    android:layout_height="178dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_progress_background"
```

image is coming like attached snapshot

[image: attached snapshot]

Answer (score 2):

**edged_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:height="50dp" android:width="50dp" />
    <stroke android:width="10dp"
        android:dashGap="4dp"
        android:dashWidth="1dp"
        android:color="#000"/>
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

Hope this helps, do some customizations according to your need.

**P.S. size tag is just to maintain aspect ratio. Its only the stroke tag that you need to change.**

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
      
        <shape android:shape="ring"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <stroke android:width="10dp"
            android:dashGap="4dp"
            android:dashWidth="1dp"
            android:color="#000"/>
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: using above code i am getting two circle one is inner and second one is outer why ?

Comment: If you apply stroke to ring, you will obviously get two strokes.

Comment: I want only ring shape to draw as per attached  image and it is not a progress bar what should I do ?

Comment: did you try my exact xml then? cant you cross check that i am using **oval** with **stroke** but not with **ring** ?

Comment: with oval it is coming too large but i want shape as a ring not oval & its too large also

Comment: Bro , I clearly mentioned in the answer, this is just a sample, you can customize it according to your use. make stroke width as 3dp, dash gap as 2dp and dash width as 1dp. And for this point **but i want shape as a ring not oval** the stroke that you are working with is itself a ring, oval shape is kind of support and hence the color is set to transparent.

Comment: And yea, one more request, I appreciate you are trying to do something on your with the help of SO, but for time being copy paste my exact xml to your drawable, dont use any selectors or layer-list, dont use any ring shape, just copy paste, only thing that you are supposed to change is height and width of `imageview`, `dashwidth`, `stroke width` and `dash gap`. Please try this and then try to understand what is happening.

Comment: If i am using your code then oval shape is covering whole screen as oval shape and if i am changing width,height as 10 dp no changes is going on also changed dashwidth, stroke width and dash gap. But no change it is coming as a whole screen.

Comment: What are the dimensions you are using for your imageview?